# MVC4 Client Site Split Dropdowns Date Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I've been trying to get some custom client site date validation working and so far I cannot seem to get it to work properly.

I have a custom date editor defined like this:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    if (Model.HasValue)
    {
        int day = Model.Value.Day;
        int month = Model.Value.Month;
        int year = Model.Value.Year;
    }

    List<SelectListItem> days = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value.Day == i});
    }

    List<SelectListItem> months = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        months.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value.Month == i});
    }

    List<SelectListItem> years = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var minYear = DateTime.Now.Year - 100;
    var maxYear = DateTime.Now.Year - 18;

    for (int i = maxYear; i >= minYear; i--)
    {
        years.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value.Year == i });
    }
}

@Html.DropDownList("days", days, "Day", new { @class="form__select" } )
@Html.DropDownList("months", months, "Month", new { @class="form__select" } )
@Html.DropDownList("years", years, "Year", new { @class="form__select" } )
```

And I have a custom validation attribute defined like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class DoBValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        List<ModelClientValidationRule> clientRules = new List<ModelClientValidationRule>();

        ModelClientValidationRule validDateRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date.",
            ValidationType = "validdate"
        };
        validDateRule.ValidationParameters.Add("dayelement", metadata.PropertyName + ".days");
        validDateRule.ValidationParameters.Add("monthelement", metadata.PropertyName + ".months");
        validDateRule.ValidationParameters.Add("yearelement", metadata.PropertyName + ".years");
        clientRules.Add(validDateRule);

        return clientRules;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DateTime dateResult;

        int day = Convert.ToInt32(validationContext.Items["days"]);
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(validationContext.Items["months"]);
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(validationContext.Items["years"]);

        // Put date parts together and check is valid...
        if (DateTime.TryParse(year + "/" + month + "/" + day, out dateResult))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        // Not valid
        return new ValidationResult(string.Format(ErrorMessageString, validationContext.DisplayName));
    }
}
```

In order to (try) and wire all this together I also have this in my JavaScript:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
'validdate', // notice this is coming from how you named your validation rule
['dayelement'],
['monthelement'],
['yearelement'],
function (options) {
    options.rules['datepartcheck'] = options.params;
    options.messages['datepartcheck'] = options.message;
    }
);
jQuery.validator.addMethod('datepartcheck', function (value, element, params) {
    var year = params[2];
    var month = params[1];
    var day = params[0];

    var birthDate = year + '/' + month-1 + '/' + day;
    var isValid = true;

    try {
        // datepicker is a part of jqueryUI.
        // include it and you can take advantage of .parseDate:
        $.datepicker.parseDate('yy/mm/dd', birthDate);
    }
    catch (error) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}, '');
```

I've put a breakpoint on all these methods but the `GetClientValidationRules` method is never called which I think means that the rules are never going to be applied to the HTML for one thing.

What am I doing wrong here?  I just cannot figure it out.  If I could I would ditch all of it and use a plain datepicker but the client is insistent on this format.

**UPDATE**

Just to be clear in the generated HTML the controls generated are three `<select>` inputs.

I'm wondering if it might be better to split this into three separate `int` properties on my model and use a range validator instead.

Comment: Your generating rules for a for your `DateTime` property but best guess is you don't actually generate a form control (e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.yourDateProperty)` - which would generate `<input ... data-val-validdate-dayelement="someValue" .../>`) so the client side rules will never be applied.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  In the view the code has `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DoB)` which uses the Editor Template listed in the question.

Comment: Yes, but that is generate 3 dropdownslist unrelated to your model. It does not generate `@Html.TextBoxFor(m = m.DoB)` so you never generate the relevant `data-val-validdate` attribute(s) so `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` will not be able to parse the element and add the rules (not to mention the issues you face posting this back - I assume you must have a custom `ModelBinder`?) I think you taking the wrong approach here, but just for testing purpose, can you add `@Html.TextBoxFor(m = m.DoB)` to your `EditorTemplate` to see if anything now works.

Comment: I do have a custom model binder.  In fact I just did a quick test where I have separated the day dropdown into a separate Int property with a Range validator applied and that is all working great.  I think you're right I'm going to move away from this solution and separate things out and go from there.  This is a silly amount of code just for a date of birth.

Comment: I would suggest a simple view model approach (3 `int` properties for day, month and year) so you can get strongly typed binding without the `EditorTemplate` and without the custom `ModelBinder`. It would be possible to create a create client side validation with a bit of work, but you could just start by using the `DateTime.TryParse(..)` method in the POST method and return a `ModelState` error if not valid.

Comment: Exactly the approach I decided to switch to.  So much simpler a less error prone.

Comment: And it would be even simpler and less error prone if we didn't have idiot clients :)

Comment: Tell me about it.  I picked this work up from an agency in London who have zero .NET experience (hence contracting me to do it) and it's things like this that I would advise against immediately.  The site is completely UK centric as well which means you could use the jQuery UI picker locked to a single date format ... easier for everyone including the user ... ho hum ...

Comment: Thanks for the time though chap.